# Disable postproccessing camera/image transformations on the HoloLens?

Tags: hololens

From my understanding, the hololens provides just a prediction of the head tracking to the unity app (or other game engine app), after which the camera is positioned. In a postprocessing step, probably after the unity app generated the image, the image is transformed to the newest, actual head tracking measurement. The result is great for room-fixed holograms and bad for camera-fixed holograms.

I have two questions: (a) Can you confirm or disprove this? and (b) Are there any related settings accessible for the user, like disable the post-transformation?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Currently HoloLens does not support this use case. However, you can provide more information about your business request and submit a feature request via feedback hub on new feature request to be considered in future releases of HoloLens OS and devices. If it's a hot impacted feature, it will be possible to be given priority to jump in the development schedule.

For how to post feedback request, you can follow this doc: [Send feedback to Microsoft with the Feedback Hub app.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4021566/windows-10-send-feedback-to-microsoft-with-feedback-hub-app)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I think it misses my point. The hololens is changing/transforming my unity-generated-image based on the newest tracking data of the sensors. Same thing will happen in orientation-only mode.

Comment: @HansS Could you post more information about your business request? If you want to fix holograms to a specified position and offset it from the player, the Orbital Solver in MRTK can implement this idea without even writing any code: https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/README_Solver.html#orbital

Comment: @HansS Hi, some changes I made to this answer, please follow the guide to post feedback.